# How should I migrate an ExpressionEngine 1 site with Photo Gallery Module?

Tags: ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I have an existing site that I'm upgrading from ExpressionEngine 1.6.7 to ExpressionEngine 2.7.0 but the problem that I'm running into is that the [Photo Gallery Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-gallery-module) is installed. Of course there is no upgrade available for ExpressionEngine 2. Can someone suggest the best upgrade path for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solspace has the [Solspace Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) Module with [Solspace Gallery Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer_gallery_assets/) designed to do just this.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I didn't know Solspace made that.